# Parse XML View from String

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to parse an XML string and use it as a UI5 view?

I like to do something like this:

```js
var sXML = `<mvc:View
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  controllerName="controller.App"
  displayBlock="true"
>
  <App>...</App>
</mvc:View>`;

var oView = sap.ui.view({
  id: "idstart1",
  view: sXML,
  type: "XML"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The factory function **`sap.ui.*view` is deprecated.** Use the [API `sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView.create`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.XMLView#methods/sap.ui.core.mvc.XMLView.create) instead, with the string value assigned to `definition`.

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
], XMLView => XMLView.create({
  definition:`<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true">
    <App xmlns="sap.m">
      <Page title="My String View" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
        <Text text="Hello, world!"/>
      </Page>
    </App>
  </mvc:View>`,
}).then(view => view.placeAt("content")));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```