# How to programmatically create fragment using XML string

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have a string containing XML fragment definition, and I'd like to create a control using it.

Example of an XML string:

```xml
var sFrag = "<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns='sap.m' xmlns:core='sap.ui.core'>
    <Dialog showHeader='false' class='transparentBG dialogScrollHeight100' contentWidth='90%' afterClose='dialogAddNewAfterclose'>
        <content>
            <Button text='X' press='closeDialog'/>
            <Text text='Hello Meirav!'/>
            <HBox alignItems='Center'>
                <Label text='Product Name: '/>
                <Label text='{currentProduct&gt;/Name}'/>
            </HBox>
            <HBox height='30px'/>
            <HBox alignItems='Center'>
                <Label text='Product Price: '/>
                <Input value='{currentProduct&gt;/Price}'/>
            </HBox>
            <HBox height='30px' />
            <Button text='Save Update' press='saveUpdateFromFrag'/>
        </content>
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>"
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, similar to [`XMLView.create`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44874712/5846045), Fragment also supports creating control(s) from an XML string.

## UI5 ≥ 1.58

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
  "sap/m/Button",
], async (Fragment, Button) => {
  "use strict";

  const dialog = await Fragment.load({
    definition: `<Dialog xmlns="sap.m"
      title="My Dialog"
      class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
      <Text text="Some Dialog content.." />
      <beginButton>
        <Button id="myBeginButton"
          text="Handle Event from Fragment"
          press=".onBeginButtonPress" />
      </beginButton>
    </Dialog>`,
    controller: { // can be just "this" in a Controller definition.
      onBeginButtonPress: () => alert("Event handler triggered!"),
    },
  });
  new Button({
    text: "Open Dialog",
    press: () => dialog.open(),
  }).placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script defer id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

[API Reference: `sap/ui/core/Fragment.load`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.Fragment#methods/sap.ui.core.Fragment.load)

PS: The [`<FragmentDefinition>` is only required if the fragment definition contains multiple root nodes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69151528/5846045) This is not the case here, hence, it can be removed.

## UI5 ≤ 1.56

If an older version is used, you'll have to fall back on the deprecated API [`sap.ui.xmlfragment`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui#methods/sap.ui.xmlfragment).

```js
const fragmentContent = `<Dialog xmlns="sap.m"><!-- ... --></Dialog>`;
const dialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment({ fragmentContent }, this);
```

Instead of `definition`, the string content needs to be assigned to the property `fragmentContent`, and the controller instance should be passed as the 2nd argument (`this`).

Comment: @m.w Sure, no problem. Just updated my answer above.