# Why to wrap a `Dialog` with `FragmentDefinition`?

Tags: sapui5

An UI5 dialog can be defined directly as a `Dialog`:

```xml
<Dialog
    xmlns = "sap.m"
    id = "helloDialog"
    title = "Hello {/recipient/name}">
    <beginButton>
        <Button
            text = "{i18n>dialogCloseButtonText}"
            press = ".onCloseDialog" />
    </beginButton>
</Dialog>
```

Or can be wrapped by a `FragmentDefinition`:

```xml
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns:core = "sap.ui.core"
    xmlns = "sap.m">

    <Dialog
        id = "helloDialog"
        title = "Hello {/recipient/name}">
        <beginButton>
            <Button
                text = "{i18n>dialogCloseButtonText}"
                press = ".onCloseDialog" />
        </beginButton>
    </Dialog>

</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

As far as I understand, a `FragmentDefinition` provides a higher degree of reuse since it doesn't depend on any view's controller but can be initialized with a custom controller using `sap.ui.core.Fragment.load()`:

```js
this._oDialog = await Fragment.load({
    controller: fragmentController,
    id: oView.getId(),
    name: "webapp.view.MyDialog"
});
```

However, according to the [documentation](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/04129b2798c447368f4c8922c3c33cd7), starting UI5 1.93, the `loadFragment()` function is available on every controller instance extending `sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller` and this API has several advantages over the generic `sap.ui.core.Fragment.load()` function.

If I use a `loadFragment()`, should I still wrap a `Dialog` with `FragmentDefinition`? I've tried both implementations, both of them work and I see a dialog on a view, so what are the benefits of using `FragmentDefinition` if I still can directly call a `Dialog` with `loadFragment()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<core:FragmentDefinition>` is a runtime artifact that is **not part of the DOM** but serves only the purpose of **wrapping multiple XML root nodes** in `*.fragment.xml` documents. I.e.:

#### Fragment with multiple root nodes

<sup>From the [topic "Fragments with Multiple Root Nodes"](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/23b9c779c2274213a281c1fc46b4962b)</sup>

```xml
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"> <!--mandatory-->
  <Label text="..." />
  <Input />
  <Button text="..." />
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

> As **XML documents need to have exactly one root node**, to achieve XML fragments with multiple root nodes, an additional `<FragmentDefinition>` tag needs to be added as root element.

#### Fragment with a single root node

<sup>From the [sample `sap.m.ActionSheet`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.ActionSheet/sample/sap.m.sample.ActionSheet/code/view/ActionSheet.fragment.xml)</sup>

```xml
<!-- No need to wrap this single root node with <FragmentDefinition> -->
<ActionSheet id="actionSheet"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  core:require="{ MessageToast: 'sap/m/MessageToast' }"
  title="Choose Your Action"
  showCancelButton="true"
  placement="Bottom">
  <Button
    text="Accept"
    icon="sap-icon://accept"
    press="MessageToast.show('Selected action is ' + ${$source>/text})" />
  <!-- ... -->
  <Button
    text="Other"
    press="MessageToast.show('Selected action is ' + ${$source>/text})"
  />
</ActionSheet>
```

As such, it is simply unnecessary for `<Dialog>` fragments too to use `<core:FragmentDefinition>`.

---

### Note

- The above applies only to XML fragments. JS fragments, for example, do not need `FragmentDefinition`. `FragmentDefinition` is not even a module you can require.
- Whether the fragment was *created* via `this.loadFragment`, `Fragment.load()`, ...etc doesn't matter. `<FragmentDefinition>` plays a role only for the *definition* of fragments.

Comment: I think it's more clean to load the required namespaces in a separate element. While it might be unnecessary from a technical point, I prefer it to adding the namespace declarations to the Dialog element.