# Dynamically create UI5-Controls with properties from json-string. Problems with events in json-string

Tags: sapui5

in my actual development i create an app which needs to create UI5-Controls dynmaically at runtime from an database customizing-table.

As an simplyfied example when creating an input field:

```
var loProObj = JSON.parse(pData.TEMPLATE);
var loInp = new sap.m.Input(loProObj);
```

This works so far for most of the properties when pData.TEMPLATE is a JSON-String. 
But it does not work for Event-Method Properties.Then i get an error like: *Uncaught TypeError: I.fFunction.call is not a function*

So as simpliefied JSON-String for code above take this string:

```
'{"value":"{boundVariable}","change":"onChange"}'
```

When this string is parsed (remember its a string comming from a database to be parsed to JSON, not a JSON-Object), onChange is still a string. this might be the problem. But what can i do to transport the information about the eventhandler methods in a json-string?

Any hints would be great

Kind regards
MatHay

Comment: Looks like there is no standard approach for this case. There are, however, solutions if the JSON text defines a whole view **or** if the definition is in XML format. Then you could make use of standard APIs to create controls out of strings. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: Hi. Yes that could be an option. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62095659/5846045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62088587/dynamically-create-ui5-controls-with-properties-from-json-string-problems-with#comment109823565_62088587), there are public APIs by which controls can be created from string values.

### Given: UI definition in XML format

- [Creating view from XML string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44874712/5846045)
- [Creating control from XML string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61367537/5846045)

### Given: view definition in JSON format

Same as `XMLView.create` but using [`JSONView.create`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.JSONView#methods/sap.ui.core.mvc.JSONView.create) instead:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/JSONView",
], JSONView => JSONView.create({
  definition: `{
    "Type":"sap.ui.core.mvc.JSONView",
    "content": [
      {
        "Type":"sap.m.Input",
        "width": "12rem",
        "placeholder": "Edit me",
        "change": "alert('Sample global handler triggered')"
      }
    ]
  }`,
}).then(view => view.placeAt("content"))));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

[Doc: JSON View](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f285256f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)

---

Unfortunately, there is no factory function for creating a single control out of JSON text yet (Currently, only XML, JS, and HTML are supported). But if it's really required, here is my attempt:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/m/Input",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
], (Input, JSONModel) => {
  "use strict";
  
  const myController = {
    onInit: function() {
      createControlViaJSON({
        definition: `{
          "placeholder": "{/myPlaceHolder}",
          "change": "onInputChange",
          "width": "12rem"
        }`,
        TargetControl: Input,
        controller: this,
      }).setModel(new JSONModel({ myPlaceHolder: "Edit me" }))
        .addStyleClass("sapUiTinyMargin")
        .placeAt("content");
    },
    onInputChange: function(event) {
      alert(`You typed: ${event.getParameter("value")}`);
    },
  };
  
  // Emulating controller initialization:
  myController.onInit();
  
  // Could be a separate module:
  function createControlViaJSON({ id, definition, TargetControl, controller }) {
    // Very primitive sample! Ignoring aggregations, associations, etc..
    const control = new TargetControl(id);
    JSON.parse(definition, (key, value) => {
      if (typeof controller[value] == "function") {
        control.applySettings({
          [key]: [controller[value], controller],
        });
      } else if (key) {
        control.applySettings({
          [key]: value,
        });
      }
    });
    return control;
  }

}));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`loProObj.change = this[loProObj.change]`

This converts the string `"onChange"` (or any other event name) into the actual function (if it is available within the `this` context). This function can then be called when the event is triggered.

If you need to access `this` in your event handler I suggest:

`loProObj.change = this[loProObj.change].bind(this)`

Comment: Hi Marc, unfortunatly this does not really help. So the coding has to "know" all event properties, get it from the json-object and has to call the setter or your code snippet. but the idea is to have created the object completly without additional "logic" from the json-object in the constructor. normally one would have the function as function-object in the object in the constructor. i thought there might be a way to define a function object as a string in my json-string..?!